# Extend Volume Group using Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I have trying to extend the VG via ansible passing the pvname by variable, however I really don't understand why is not working.
Below you can see my code.

Variable file:

```
new_disk: 
   - diskname: /dev/sdc
    
pvname: /dev/sdb1, dev/sdc1    
vgname: datavg
lvm_settings:
  - lv_name: datalv  
    lv_size: +100%FREE
    fs_name: ansible_fs_test
   lvpath: /dev/mapper/datavg-datalv
filesystem_type: ext4
```

tasks file:

```
 include_vars: "{{ vm_name }}.yml"
    
- name: First disk partition settings
  block:
    - name: Create a new primary partition
      community.general.parted:
        device: "{{ item.diskname }}"
        number: 1
        state: present
      with_items: "{{ new_disk }}"
      register: partition_status
  rescue:
    - name: Debug messages to check the error
      debug:
        msg: "{{ partition_status }}"

- name: Extending the Volume Group
  community.general.lvg:
    vg: "{{ vgname }}"
    pvs: "{{ pvname }}"
    pvresize: yes
```

Below, you can see the error message:

TASK [resize_fs_linux : Extending the Volume Group] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************fatal: [10.1.33.225]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Device /home/icc-admin/ dev/sdc1 not found."}

Do you know have any idea why is not working?
I really appreciate your help and time
Best Regards,

Comment: There is is a typo on your second device path which should start with a `/` => `/dev/sdc1`. Moreover; although I doubt it has an influence, I would still remove the spaces in the comma separated list (as shown in [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/lvg_module.html#examples)=> `/dev/sdb1,/dev/sdc1`

Answer (score 1):

For it works that way:

Variable file

```
  diskname: 
      - /dev/sdb
      - /dev/sdc
    
    
    disks_settings:
      - vgname: datavg
        pvname:
          - /dev/sdb1
          - /dev/sdc1
    
    
    lvm_settings:
      - vgname: datavg
        lv_name: datalv  
        lv_size: +100%FREE
        fs_name: ansible_fs_test
        lvpath: /dev/mapper/datavg-datalv
    
    filesystem_type: ext4
```

Tasks file:

```
 ---
    # tasks file for resize_fs_linux
    - include_vars: "{{ vm_name }}.yml"
        
    - name: First disk partition settings
      block:
        - name: Create a new primary partition
          community.general.parted:
            device: "{{ item }}"
            number: 1
            state: present
          with_items: "{{ diskname }}"
          register: partition_status
          run_once: true
      rescue:
        - name: Debug messages to check the error
          debug:
            msg: "{{ partition_status }}"
    
    - name: Extending the Volume Group
      community.general.lvg:
        vg: "{{ item.vgname }}"
        pvs: "{{ item.pvname }}"
        pvresize: yes
      with_items: "{{ disks_settings }}"

- name: Increasing the filesystems
  community.general.lvol:
    vg: "{{ vgname }}"
    lv: "{{ item.lv_name }}"
    size: "{{ item.lv_size }}"
    resizefs: true
  with_items: "{{ lvm_settings }}"
```